# Perform functions together

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a doubt how to perform two functions in the same time. I guess I should use a Promise.All() but I don't know how to use.

Hi have a code structured in this way:

```
scan1(){
this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if (
        (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) ||
        (device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model))
      ) {
        this.setState({ deviceId1: device.id });
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        this.setState({deviceName1: device})
        console.log("(this.state.deviceName1 = device:): " + this.state.deviceName1);
        device
          .connect()
          .then(() => {
            console.log(" ");
            this.scan2();
       //..code...

scan2(){
this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }
      if (
        (device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model)) ||
        (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model))
      ) {
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        this.setState({ deviceId2: device.id });
        this.setState({deviceName2: device})
        device
          .connect()
          .then(() => {
            this.deviceService1(this.state.deviceName1);
            this.deviceService2(this.state.deviceName2);
       // .... code.... 

deviceService1(device) {
    console.log("device.name: " + device.name)
    if (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model) ||
      device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model)) { 
      device
        .discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("(this.setupNotifications1")
          this.setupNotifications1(device);
        })
        //... code..

  deviceService2(device) {
    console.log("device.name: " + device.name)
    if (device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model) ||
      device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) { 
      device
        .discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("(this.setupNotifications2")
          this.setupNotifications2(device);
        })
       //... code...
```

In the two function setupNotifications1(device) and setupNotifications2(device) I recover data from external device. The problem is here infact in this way I recover data first from a device and then from the other one, so I have more data from the first device.

Now how can I do to execute this two function setupNotification together?

Thank you!

Comment: Even you setupNotifications at the same time, the external devices would return differently

Comment: check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: so you say that there is a problem with recovering data from device 1 first. what exactly is the problem with that? and how would running both functions parallel solve that problem? because if you recover data, you are doing just that. getting data. unless the data of the first device depends on the data of the 2nd device, there shouldnt be any problem with this conceptually

Comment: the problem is that when I go to click the stop button I have more data from the first device that other.

Comment: @cereme I know this page, I don't know how to use the promise xD